# Difficulty adding unique event listener to created <div> elements via a for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project to learn some JavaScript, the goal is to serve up emails dynamically in a single page web application. The HTML of the application has been created using the createElement JS method. So far I have managed to display the "inbox" page with all of the emails in it, as illustrated below:

[image]

I'm currently attempting to make each of these individual emails clickable through the use of an addEventListener. The issue that I'm having is that whenever I click any of the emails, the first email in the inbox (id:1, subject:Test Email) is rendered and it is not possible to view any of the others.

[image]

I can see that the same email.id is being applied to the event listener for all of the created divs, despite all of the divs being created correctly, with all of the information from the corresponding emails.

Here is the load mailbox JS, which renders all of the emails within the inbox:

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#single-view').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

  // GET request
  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {

    // Print emails to console
    console.log(emails);

    // Iterate through each email
    for(var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
      var email = emails[i];
        
      // Create div and append email content to HTML
      var emaildiv = document.createElement('div');
      emaildiv.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
      emaildiv.style.borderColor = 'black';
      emaildiv.style.borderWidth = '0.1rem';
      emaildiv.style.borderRadius = '0';
      emaildiv.style.marginBottom = '0.2rem';
      emaildiv.style.padding = '0.3rem';
      emaildiv.innerHTML = `<b>${email.sender}</b> --- ${email.subject}<br>${email.timestamp}`;
      
      // If individual email selected then view email
      emaildiv.addEventListener('click', () => view_email(email));

      // Populate div HTML with emails
      document.querySelector('#emails-view').append(emaildiv); 
      console.log(email.read);

      // Colour backgrounds based on whether emails have been read
      if (email.read == true) {
        emaildiv.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
      }

      console.log(email);
  }   
});}
```

Here is the view email JS, which is supposed to render the HTML of the individual email:

```
// View email
function view_email(email) {
  console.log(email.id);

  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#single-view').style.display = 'block';

  // GET request
  fetch(`/emails/${email["id"]}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    
    // Create div, set class, and append email content to HTML
    var reademail = document.createElement('div');
    reademail.innerHTML = '';
    reademail.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    reademail.style.borderColor = 'black';
    reademail.style.borderWidth = '0.1rem';
    reademail.style.borderRadius = '0';
    reademail.style.marginBottom = '0.2rem';
    reademail.style.padding = '0.3rem';
    reademail.innerHTML = `
    <b>From:</b> ${email.sender}<br>
    <b>To:</b> ${email.recipients}<br>
    <b>Subject:</b> ${email.subject}<br>
    <b>Timestamp:</b> ${email.timestamp}<br>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="Reply">Reply</button>
    <hr>
    ${email.body}`;

    // Populate div HTML with emails
    document.querySelector('#single-view').append(reademail); 

    // Mark unread emails as read
    if (email.read === 'false') {
      fetch(`/emails/${email}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            read: true
        })
      })
    }      
});
}
```

Here is an example (dummy data) what is stored in the email GET response:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "sender": "user@example.com",
        "recipients": ["user@example.com"],
        "subject": "Hello!",
        "body": "Hello, world!",
        "timestamp": "Oct 24 2020, 12:00 AM",
        "read": false,
        "archived": false
}
```

I have tried hard-coding in the id for each of the other emails into the view email JS and can see that the functionality works as required (displays the email).

Consequently, I know that the issue is to do with the load mailbox JS above, and likely how the event listener is being applied within the for loop. If anybody could shine some light on how to get a unique event listener applied to each individual div, that would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you see inside `console.log(emails);` , list of emails as object , with different ids ? and you see same id in `console.log(email.id);` in your load function ?

Comment: Hi @BrightFaith - Yes, that's correct. :)

Comment: i cant find out the problem , but if i was writing this , i would assign the `id` as a `custom attribute` to the element using `data-attribute=""` , then write a global click event listener for `document` checking if `e.target` is one of my email elements , then get the attribute of it using `getAttribute` method of JS and pass to the load function

Comment: Thank you for having a look for me, and for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the way your declaring the email within the loop:

```
var email = emails[i];
```

Because of scoping, you create a single closure around `email` and all iterations of the loop use one value. Change it to `let` for block level scope so that each loop iteration gets its own value to work with:

```
let email = emails[i];
```

**Other:**

To make your code simpler to read and maintain, don't set up inline styles. Instead create CSS Classes and just apply/remove the classes as needed. So instead of:

```
document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector('#single-view').style.display = 'block';
```

Just make a CSS class called, say `.hidden`, like this:

```
.hidden { display:none; }
```

And, when an element needs that class or needs it removed do:

```
someElement.classList.add("hidden");
someElement.classList.remove("hidden");
```

Similarly, instead of this:

```
// Create div, set class, and append email content to HTML
var reademail = document.createElement('div');
reademail.innerHTML = '';
reademail.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
reademail.style.borderColor = 'black';
reademail.style.borderWidth = '0.1rem';
reademail.style.borderRadius = '0';
reademail.style.marginBottom = '0.2rem';
reademail.style.padding = '0.3rem';
```

Make a CSS Class, like this:

```
.readEmail {
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.3rem;
}
```

And then just add it to the new element (also, don't use `.innerHTML` when your string doesn't contain any HTML because `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications):

```
var reademail = document.createElement('div');
reademail.textContent = '';
reademail.classList.add("readEmail");
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution & explanation Scott, that has resolved it for me - really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional notes, will go back through and add those changes in also - I was trying to figure out how to add a class before, but nothing seemed to work. Will give classList.add a go now. Really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `emaildiv.addEventListener('click', () => view_email(email));` into the `load_mailbox` function you are assigning the reference of `email` object that change in every loop.
Because in the `view_email` function you need only the email's id, I suggest you to pass only `email.id` param to this function, like this:

```
emaildiv.addEventListener('click', () => view_email(email.id));
```

`email.id` is a primitive value (a Number) and Javascript pass as value and not as reference. So, the `view_email` function became:

```
// View email
function view_email(emailId) {
  console.log(emailId);

  ...

  // GET request
  fetch(`/emails/${emailId}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    
   ...

   });
}
```

Comment: It is generally a better idea to pass a reference to an element than to a property of an element, so the way the OP is doing it now is really best. The reason is that if you only pass the value of a property and then the function needs the value of some other property, you have to go get your reference to the element all over again (which in a loop could be problematic). If you pass a reference to the element, the receiver can access any/all property values very easily. Also, `email.id` is not a Number, it's a string.

Comment: So, just to make the point, if the OP took your advice and passed `email.id`, then the `view_email` function will have trouble when it gets to: `then(email => ` because no reference to the `email` element would have been passed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus in the JSON posted by Tjm92 (that rappresent an email object, I supposed) the value contained in the `id` attribute is a Number (1, in the example). Also, I think that the function `view_email` has no trouble with param `email` because the function itself fetch the email newly, and `email` in `then(email => ` is the JSON of `fetch`

Comment: You're right about the `email.id` (I didn't see the JSON in the question), but the `view_email` doesn't fetch the `email`. It uses `email` to get the `id`. And, in your suggestion, you don't even have `email` available to use. Regardless, my original point remains, it's better to pass references to DOM elements, than to properties of those elements.

Comment: I'm sorry @ScottMarcus, but you’re wrong. In the `view_email` function in my example there is a fetch `fetch(``/emails/${emailId}``).then(response => response.json()).then(email => { ... })` that resolve with the response to `/emails/${emailId}` and return an Object called `email`. The `email` param pass to the function is not the same.. The `email` object get from `response.json()` has its scope that is different from the scope of `view_email` function

Comment: *Regardless, my original point remains, it's better to pass references to DOM elements, than to properties of those elements.*